# why count query with where condition needs shuffling of data?

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

By changing the parameter "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", the performance of below query is varying. Does the below query needs shuffling?

> Select count(*) from table where id is not null

The other doubt I am having is, what is the line between two stages in below image. Is it the significance of shuffling?

[image]

Comment: I guess the actual records do not need be exchanges between partitions, but the aggegator needs to be exchanged (containing `count` as the only information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first stage, all task calculate individual task level count and then aggregated count has transferred to second stage, where second stage sum up all the count and give the final count.